# How to create custom error messages using AJV?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, typescript, ajv

I am trying to add custom error messages to my application input field but when I try to get this error:

> Error: strict mode: unknown keyword: "errorMessage"

Here's the code.

file one:

```
import Ajv, { JSONSchemaType } from 'ajv'
import addFormats from 'ajv-formats'

const ajv = new Ajv({ allErrors: true, $data: true })

addFormats(ajv)

export const emailSchema: JSONSchemaType<string> = {
  type: 'string',
  minLength: 1,
  format: 'email',
//this is whats causing the error
  errorMessage: {
    minLength: 'This field cannot be empty.',
    format: 'Must be a valid email address.',
  },
}

export const validateEmail = (value: string) => {
  return {
    isValid: emailValidator(value),
    error: emailValidator.errors ? emailValidator.errors[0]?.message : '',
  }
}
```

file two:

```
import Ajv, { JSONSchemaType } from 'ajv'
import { LoginCredentials } from './types'
import addFormats from 'ajv-formats'
import {
  emailSchema,
  passwordSchema,
  recaptchaTockenSchema,
} from '../../utils/validation/auth-validation'
import { getFormattedErrors } from '../../utils/validation/formatter'

const ajv = new Ajv({ allErrors: true, $data: true })

addFormats(ajv)

const credentialsSchema: JSONSchemaType<LoginCredentials> = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    emailAddress: emailSchema,
    password: passwordSchema,
    recaptchaToken: recaptchaTockenSchema,
  },
  required: ['emailAddress', 'password', 'recaptchaToken'],
  additionalProperties: false,
}

const credentialsValidator = ajv.compile(credentialsSchema)

export const validateCredentials = (credentials: LoginCredentials) => {
  return {
    isValid: credentialsValidator(credentials),
    errors: getFormattedErrors(credentialsValidator.errors),
  }
}
```

I would like a different message depending on the error for instance minLength or format but I would like to define what this error message says, how can I do this?

Comment: You should specify option strict: false when initializing Ajv, then you can add arbitrary properties such as errorMessage to your schema: 
`const ajv = new Ajv({ allErrors: true, strict: false, $data: true })`

Answer (score 8):

you need to use 'ajv-errors' lib separately. Something like that:

```
import Ajv from 'ajv';
import addFormats from 'ajv-formats'
import ajvErrors from 'ajv-errors';

const ajv = new Ajv({ allErrors: true, $data: true });
addFormats(ajv);
ajvErrors(ajv);
```

Comment: Thank you for this!! I've been searching for days.